# Showing a list on OS X todayextension

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit

Alike default "Stocks" todayextension, I would like have a list, and allow user to add item when information icon is clicked.
I have placed NSTableView and binded an Array, though it looked totally different. It looked like reglurar table, and no transparent to the background.
What could be the controll look like Stocks?

Comment: Set `Highlight` of the table view to `Source List`

Comment: Thank you! I turned to be what I wanted.

Comment: Adding self.myTableView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor() on viewDidLoad affected nice transparency